# How to make image responsive? HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following image:

```css
.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" align="left" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
```

How would I make the image responsive?

### Expected Output:

[image]

See how the image is positioned like that? It's not fit the entire page, as its width and height are shortened. **I want my image above to be just like that when viewed on a smaller device, otherwise, it should be as it is shown in the output above.**

I tried changing the width and height of the image and used a media query but it did not work, so I removed the media query. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In your image tag, you have a property `align="left"` that is actually deprecated.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/align

After removing that `align="left"` from your image tag, here's one way to do it:

```css
/* Added code */

img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    height: 200px; /* image height for larger screen only */
  }
}


/* Your sample code */

.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" width="370" height="500">
<div class="aligned">
  <div class="p">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
      a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
      vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
    </p>
    <blockquote>
      Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
      <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
    </blockquote>

  </div>
```

Comment: I am not getting the image to be outputted like in the expected output I showed

Comment: I thought a small hint would do it, but I updated the answer with the whole code.

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust the height of the image on large screen? I tried changing the values in index.html but it does not work

Comment: You can do it inside CSS. The height value doesn't work in your HTML because I have overritten it in the CSS, by adding `height: auto`. If you want a different height on larger screen, simply add it inside the media query. (Example added) 
Mind you that adding both width and height will stretch the image. Making either value `auto` is easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent element a `flex` layout that changes using a media query. You don't need to use floats in this case.

You're missing a closing `div` tag for `<div class='aligned'>`

You should also let the width of the `blockquote` be `auto` until the screen gets to the size you want it to be on desktop.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}

.aligned {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.p {
  padding: 15px;
}

img {
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  blockquote {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

blockquote cite:before {
  content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" align="left" width="370" height="500">
  <div class="aligned">
    <div class="p">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
        a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
        vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
        a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
        vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis facilisis consequat. Aenean commodo laoreet mattis. Sed consequat massa magna, quis finibus libero ornare eget. Sed elementum, metus quis elementum porta, lacus dui rhoncus nulla,
        a convallis arcu ipsum id erat. Mauris maximus congue mollis. Proin sodales non risus eu porta. Duis iaculis eget quam at suscipit. Aliquam sed erat diam. Nullam dictum urna sit amet vestibulum facilisis. Proin turpis dui, ultrices sit amet tellus
        vitae, volutpat tristique turpis. Ut at pretium turpis, ut malesuada mi. Phasellus massa turpis, pretium et diam quis, iaculis sagittis justo.
      </p>
      <blockquote>
        Nothing Is Impossible. The Word Itself Says 'IM Possible'
        <cite>Audrey Hepburn</cite>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible if you can remove the body class since I am using this code in my website which already has a body class and so it would disrupt with it?

Comment: How would you do it without the `body{`?

Comment: @AbiaOmer I updated the answer to reference a parent element instead of the body.

Comment: I missed a css property. The version now is good to go.